# Xencenter server with failed disk mirror - LVM - I am unsure how to proceed

Tags: lvm, xen, citrix

I'm having a serious problem with an older server I inherited running Xencenter.  The VM would no longer boot with a VDI unavailable error.. I began troubleshooting as much as I could but I have very little knowledge on LVM and really don't want to cause any additional issues.  I'm hoping some of you experts here can assist or point me in the right direction.  I am knowledgable using linux but LVM, I really don't understand what I'm looking at with the output shown below.   I need to try to get anything I can out of the volume and get it moved to ESX.. I was in the middle of building a new server to host this particular VM and get it on something I am way more comfortable using.

Thank you for anything you can suggest to get this mounted somehow, even RO so I can copy it off.  I am very sorry if i'm missing anything.  I'm really not sure what I'm looking at here, from what I can tell, one of the disks is kaput, but if it's a mirror I should be able to mount that volume somehow? or dd a disk image over to an nfs server to mount somewhere else???

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1     46139392     83888127     18G  Microsoft basic
 2      8390656     46139391     18G  Microsoft basic
 3     83888128     84936703    512M  BIOS boot parti
 5         2048      8390655      4G  Microsoft basic
 6     84936704     87033855      1G  Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--17d1d6ae--7b5b--d2e6--ffa9--34f42e56bb48-MGT: 4 MB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

fdisk: cannot open /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--17d1d6ae--7b5b--d2e6--ffa9--34f42e56bb48-VHD--694760ca--8e18--451b--9c47--8b42922c6a5c-missing_0_0: Input/output error
```

**vgchange -ay**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# vgchange -ay
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
  Refusing activation of partial LV VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48" now active
[root@xen1 xenstored]# vgchange -ay --activationmode partial
  PARTIAL MODE. Incomplete logical volumes will be processed.
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48" now active
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

**pvscan -v**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# pvscan -v
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Wiping internal VG cache
    Walking through all physical volumes
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    /etc/lvm/cache/.cache is empty
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
    There are 1 physical volumes missing.
  PV /dev/sdb         VG VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48   lvm2 [931.50 GiB / 931.50 GiB free]
  PV /dev/sdc         VG VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48   lvm2 [596.16 GiB / 596.16 GiB free]
  PV /dev/sdd         VG VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48   lvm2 [931.50 GiB / 931.50 GiB free]
  PV unknown device   VG VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48   lvm2 [2.73 TiB / 790.59 GiB free]
  Total: 4 [5.13 TiB] / in use: 4 [5.13 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

**cat /etc/lvm/backup/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# cat /etc/lvm/backup/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.130(2)-RHEL7 (2015-12-01): Mon Oct  2 17:53:15 2017

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing '/sbin/lvremove -f /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-06006f4d-25a9-4b02-a311-f660bc75672f'"

creation_host = "xen1"  # Linux xen1 3.10.0+10 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 12:31:44 UTC 2016 x86_64
creation_time = 1506991995      # Mon Oct  2 17:53:15 2017

VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48 {
        id = "aMkrBC-uWJk-t8aE-OxPE-RYH1-U7F1-VhedHZ"
        seqno = 98
        format = "lvm2"                 # informational
        status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
        flags = []
        extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
        max_lv = 0
        max_pv = 0
        metadata_copies = 0

        physical_volumes {

                pv0 {
                        id = "1SiYGv-LHwC-10Iz-2aV8-pHg3-KvC5-f6QQaD"
                        device = "/dev/sdb"     # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 1953525168   # 931.513 Gigabytes
                        pe_start = 22528
                        pe_count = 238464       # 931.5 Gigabytes
                }

                pv1 {
                        id = "LPdOu2-nmcV-WuOK-sXps-SRoF-faYh-6BiM5M"
                        device = "/dev/sdc"     # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 1250263728   # 596.172 Gigabytes
                        pe_start = 22528
                        pe_count = 152617       # 596.16 Gigabytes
                }

                pv2 {
                        id = "FVD2cq-j4I5-xvPp-tAdB-1lwa-HglN-hR7M2G"
                        device = "/dev/sdd"     # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 1953525168   # 931.513 Gigabytes
                        pe_start = 22528
                        pe_count = 238464       # 931.5 Gigabytes
                }

                pv3 {
                        id = "1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ"
                        device = "/dev/sde"     # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 5860533168   # 2.72902 Terabytes
                        pe_start = 22528
                        pe_count = 715394       # 2.72901 Terabytes
                }
        }

        logical_volumes {

                MGT {
                        id = "wkOhxx-6WJm-vEfK-NM7Q-f8qr-EwN6-bqcbRz"
                        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                        flags = []
                        creation_host = "localhost"
                        creation_time = 1485701988      # 2017-01-29 06:59:48 -0800
                        segment_count = 1

                        segment1 {
                                start_extent = 0
                                extent_count = 1        # 4 Megabytes

                                type = "striped"
                                stripe_count = 1        # linear

                                stripes = [
                                        "pv0", 0
                                ]
                        }
                }

                VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c {
                        id = "vY8Q6w-EWXs-d29t-wNSb-oAtf-0KjE-Zz4hdZ"
                        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                        flags = []
                        creation_host = "xen1"
                        creation_time = 1486094237      # 2017-02-02 19:57:17 -0800
                        segment_count = 1

                        segment1 {
                                start_extent = 0
                                extent_count = 513002   # 1.95695 Terabytes

                                type = "striped"
                                stripe_count = 1        # linear

                                stripes = [
                                        "pv3", 0
                                ]
                        }
                }
        }
}
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

**pvs**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# pvs
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
  PV             VG                                                 Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb       VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48 lvm2 a--  931.50g 931.50g
  /dev/sdc       VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48 lvm2 a--  596.16g 596.16g
  /dev/sdd       VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48 lvm2 a--  931.50g 931.50g
  unknown device VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48 lvm2 a-m    2.73t 790.59g
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

**lvs -v**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# lvs -v
    Using logical volume(s) on command line.
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    Found same device /dev/sdb with same pvid 1SiYGvLHwC10Iz2aV8pHg3KvC5f6QQaD
    Found same device /dev/sdc with same pvid LPdOu2nmcVWuOKsXpsSRoFfaYh6BiM5M
    Found same device /dev/sdd with same pvid FVD2cqj4I5xvPptAdB1lwaHglNhR7M2G
    /etc/lvm/cache/.cache is empty
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
    /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
    There are 1 physical volumes missing.
    There are 1 physical volumes missing.
  LV                                       VG                                                 #Seg Attr       LSize Maj Min KMaj KMin Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Cpy%Sync Log Convert LV UUID                                LProfile
  MGT                                      VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48    1 -wi-a----- 4.00m  -1  -1  253    0                                                     wkOhxx-6WJm-vEfK-NM7Q-f8qr-EwN6-bqcbRz
  VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48    1 -wi-a---p- 1.96t  -1  -1  253    2                                                     vY8Q6w-EWXs-d29t-wNSb-oAtf-0KjE-Zz4hdZ
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

** EDIT **
adding some of the xen troubleshooting, much of the same information shows here and the error message.  I've read posts to remove the SR and rescan, but I think my issue is more severe than that..

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-start vm="Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)"
Error code: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_46
Error parameters: , The VDI is not available [opterr=Command ['/sbin/lvchange', '-ay', '/dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c'] failed (5): /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686275072: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2151686332416: Input/output error
  /dev/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid 1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ.
  Refusing activation of partial LV VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48/VHD-694760ca-8e18-451b-9c47-8b42922c6a5c.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.],

[root@xen1 xenstored]# list_domains
id |                                 uuid |  state
 0 | 5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd |     R
[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-disk-list uuid=5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd
Error: No matching VMs found
[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

**and trying to force the power status**

```
[root@xen1 xenstored]# list_domains
id |                                 uuid |  state
 0 | 5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd |     R
[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-disk-list uuid=5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd
Error: No matching VMs found
[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-list
uuid ( RO)           : a1a34843-beeb-e570-fef8-ada496efbb73
     name-label ( RW): Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)
    power-state ( RO): halted


uuid ( RO)           : 5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd
     name-label ( RW): Control domain on host: xen1
    power-state ( RO): running


[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-reset-powerstate force=true vm="Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)"
[root@xen1 xenstored]# xe vm-list
uuid ( RO)           : a1a34843-beeb-e570-fef8-ada496efbb73
     name-label ( RW): Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)
    power-state ( RO): halted


uuid ( RO)           : 5947d140-648b-438b-96e3-b167c0fa5edd
     name-label ( RW): Control domain on host: xen1
    power-state ( RO): running


[root@xen1 xenstored]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a missing disk:

1. In your `vgchange` command, LVM complain about device `1nDNEE-3cTf-lq02-Bdj8-xHOu-Qrce-j0leJQ` missing.
2. In your `/etc/lvm/backup/VG_XenStorage-17d1d6ae-7b5b-d2e6-ffa9-34f42e56bb48` file, we can see that the missing device is stored in `/dev/sde` disk
3. Your `fdisk -l` doesn't report any `/dev/sde` device.

That's all ...

Comment: Thanks binarym, thats about all I could read as well, is there a way to mount this somehow without that disk?  This should be a mirror (which should be the point of mirrored disks)

I really don't want to destroy the data or cause further problems but open to suggestions of things I can try.